# Initial "See, ..." or "Look, ..." usage

Tags: word-choice, differences, word-usage, sense-verbs, see-look

Which is correct to say

```
 1. "Look , The situation was like that..." or "See, The situation was
    like that ....". 


 2. "Look , I am not involved in it..." or "See, I am not involved in
        it ....".
```

Or are  both correct in every context?

Comment: The comma after _"Look,"_ or _"See,"_ is obligatory for this use. In speech, they are pronounced with low falling intonation, and are not a part of the sentence. They're discourse markers, as @EdwinAshworth points out, and they have specific discourse uses. _"See,"_ indicates that an explanation or other argument will follow, and requests attention to detail on the part of the addressed. _"Look,"_ specifically refers to expected disagreement on the part of the addressee, but requests attention anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are most probably being used here as examples of pragmatic markers, specifically, focusing pragmatic markers. You can find them included as 'discourse markers' (a term that overlaps confusingly) on [this page](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all#hl=all&q=discourse+markers+look+now+see+right):

> expressions that should be analysed as discourse markers in some of
>   their uses: see, look,

They don't have the meaning 'Have a look at this:' in this usage - they're more like 'Hey!'

Even though they stand grammatically separate from the matrix sentence (as parentheticals), they don't trigger a capital letter in the matrix sentence if they are followed (as here) by a comma.

'Look' is more common as a focusing marker, at least in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are both correct. You cannot say in every context, but in this case they roughly mean the same thing.